# How to detect each JavaDoc block start-and-end line in a source-code file?

Tags: java, parsing, javadoc

I am creating a parsing utility, to read through a (duplicate of a) Java source-code file, and re-output it with some extra information inserted at certain points in the JavaDoc blocks.

The first step was to figure out where each JavaDoc block begins and ends. Below is the code I wrote to do that.

I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes the path to a Java source-code file, and outputs the start and end lines for each found JavaDoc block.

```
   import  java.io.File;
   import  java.io.IOException;
   import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
   import  org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
   import  org.apache.commons.io.LineIterator;
   import  xbn.io.RTIOException;
/**
   <P>Prints the start and end line-numbers for all JavaDoc blocks in a Java source-code file. The one and only parameter is the path to the file. This assumes that the JavaDoc open-comment (slash-asterisk-asterisk) is the first non-whitespace on its line. The end comment (asterisk-slash) may be anywhere on the line.</P>

   java PrintJDBlocksStartStopLineNumsXmpl C:\java_code\PrintJDBlocksStartStopLineNumsXmpl.java
 **/
 public class PrintJDBlocksStartStopLineNumsXmpl  {
    /**
       <P>The main function.</P>
     **/
    public static final void main(String[] as_1RqdJavaSourcePath)  {

       //Read command-line parameter
          String sJPath = null;
          try  {
             sJPath = as_1RqdJavaSourcePath[0];
          }  catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aibx)  {
             throw  new NullPointerException("Missing one-and-only required parameter: Path to java source-code file.");
          }
          System.out.println("Java source: " + sJPath);

       //Establish line-iterator
          LineIterator li = null;
          try  {
             li = FileUtils.lineIterator(new File(sJPath)); //Throws npx if null
          }  catch(IOException iox)  {
             throw  new RTIOException("PrintJDBlocksStartStopLinesXmpl", iox);
          }
          Pattern pTrmdJDBlockStart = Pattern.compile("^[\\t ]*/\\*\\*");

       String sDD = "..";
       int iLn = 1;
       boolean bInJDBlock = false;
       while(li.hasNext())  {
          String sLn = li.nextLine();
          if(!bInJDBlock)  {
             if(pTrmdJDBlockStart.matcher(sLn).matches())  {
                bInJDBlock = true;
                System.out.print(iLn + sDD);
             }
          }  else if(sLn.indexOf("*/") != -1)  {
             bInJDBlock = false;
             System.out.println(iLn);
          }
          iLn++;
       }
       if(bInJDBlock)  {
          throw  new IllegalStateException("Reach end of file. JavaDoc not closed.");
       }
    }
    /**
       <P>Another one</P>
     **/
    private static final void oneMoreForGoodMeasure()  {
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code]java PrintJDBlocksStartStopLineNumsXmpl C:\java_code\PrintJDBlocksStartStopLineNumsXmpl.java
Java source: C:\java_code\PrintJDBlocksStartStopLineNumsXmpl.java
8..12
14..16
54..56
```

Answer (score 0):

My original answer was the first step in creating [`FilteredLineIterator`](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/xbnjava/documentation/javadoc/com/github/xbn/linefilter/FilteredLineIterator.html).

`FilteredLineIterator` filters another string iterator (which is normally the lines in a text file), keeping or discarding each line based on the entities in which it exists: "blocks", "single line" and "stealth block" entities. Each kept line may be altered.

(`FilteredLineIterator` is part of [XBN-Java](http://xbnjava.aliteralmind.com). Download the necessary jars [here](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/xbnjava/documentation/javadoc/overview-summary.html#overview_description).)

The following example declares a "JavaDoc block" [block entity](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/xbnjava/documentation/javadoc/com/github/xbn/linefilter/entity/BlockEntity.html), and a "Java multi-line comment" [stealth entity](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/xbnjava/documentation/javadoc/com/github/xbn/linefilter/entity/StealthBlockEntity.html). The stealth entity is necessary to avoid the final line in non-JavaDoc comment blocks from incorrectly causing "end line found before block opened" errors (since both JavaDoc and non-JavaDoc comment blocks end with `*/`).

```
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.entity.KeepMatched;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.entity.EntityRequired;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.FilteredLineIterator;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.KeepUnmatched;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.Returns;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.entity.BlockEntity;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.entity.NewBlockEntityFor;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.entity.NewStealthBlockEntityFor;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.entity.StealthBlockEntity;
   import  com.github.xbn.testdev.GetFromCommandLineAtIndex;
   import  com.github.xbn.util.IncludeJavaDoc;
   import  java.util.Iterator;
/**
   <P>{@code java PrintAllJavaDocBlockStartAndEndLineNums C:\java_code\example_input\JavaClassWithOneCommentAndTwoJavaDocBlocks_input.txt}</P>
 **/
public class PrintAllJavaDocBlockStartAndEndLineNums  {
   public static final void main(String[] cmd_lineParams)  {
      //Example setup
         Iterator<String> itr = GetFromCommandLineAtIndex.fileLineIterator(
            cmd_lineParams, 0,
            null);     //debugPath
```

Example proper:

```
      StealthBlockEntity javaMlcStealth = NewStealthBlockEntityFor.javaComment(
         "comment", IncludeJavaDoc.NO,
         null,         //dbgStart (on:System.out, off:null)
         null,         //dbgEnd
         KeepMatched.YES, EntityRequired.YES, null,
         null);        //dbgLineNums

      BlockEntity javaDocBlock = NewBlockEntityFor.javaDocComment_Cfg(
         "doccomment",
         null,       //dbgStart
         null,       //dbgEnd
         EntityRequired.YES, null,
         null).      //dbgLineNums
         keepAll().build();

      FilteredLineIterator filteredItr = new FilteredLineIterator(
         itr, Returns.KEPT, KeepUnmatched.NO,
         null, null,    //dbgEveryLine and its line-range
         javaMlcStealth, javaDocBlock);

      while(filteredItr.hasNext())  {
         filteredItr.next();

         if(filteredItr.getActiveChildType().isBlock()  &&
               filteredItr.getActiveChildBlock().isStartLine())  {
            System.out.print("Block: " + filteredItr.getNextLineNum() + "..");

         }  else if(filteredItr.getActiveChildType().isBlock()  &&
               filteredItr.getActiveChildBlock().isEndLine())  {
            System.out.println(filteredItr.getNextLineNum());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Block: 9..11
Block: 13..24
Block: 28..30
```

An alternative is to print the block line numbers with automated debugging:

```
BlockEntity javaDocBlock = NewBlockEntityFor.javaDocComment_Cfg(
   "doccomment",
   null,       //dbgStart
   null,       //dbgEnd
   EntityRequired.YES, null,
   System.out).   //<--Automated line-number debugging
   keepAll().build();

FilteredLineIterator filteredItr = new FilteredLineIterator...

while(filteredItr.hasNext())  {
   filteredItr.next();
}
```

Output:

```
[9:BLOCK:"doccomment"] block-start
[11:BLOCK:"doccomment":active] block end
[13:BLOCK:"doccomment"] block-start
[24:BLOCK:"doccomment":active] block end
[28:BLOCK:"doccomment"] block-start
[30:BLOCK:"doccomment":active] block end
```

Input file:

```
/*
   Not a JavaDoc block. The following sub-mode is ignored, because it's not in a JavaDoc block.

      //sub-mode...START

      //sub-mode...END
 */
package  fully.qualified.package.name;
/**
  <P>A JavaDoc block</P>
 */
public class StayClassy  {
   /**
      <P>Another JavaDoc block</P>

      <P>info</P>        //sub-mode...START

      <P>info</P>

      <P>info</P>        //sub-mode...END

      <P>info</P>

    */
   public StayClassy()  {
      //Do stuff
   }
   /**
     <P>Does stuff.</P>
    */
   public void doStuff()  {
   }
}
```